# How to calculate the mean pixel value inside an elipse area

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I would like to compare the difference of pixel intensities inside an area and for such task i am trying to use matplotlib to draw an elipse to a tiff format file. What i would like to do is draw two elipses to distinguish the eye from the sclera, by drawing two elipses to separate both and obtain the mean values from both regions, for example:

[image]

I'd like to calculate the mean values inside the first elipse area and the second area separately, to observe the difference between those two areas.

This is the example with the elipses generated that i would like to calculate the means from inside both areas:

[Image with elipses](http://www.mediafire.com/file/jd0szb3yth2tmk4/file)

Tiff image plot for coordinates visualization:

[image]

Code used to generate elipses:

```
import matplotlib.image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
figure, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img)
ax.add_patch(mpatches.Ellipse((30, 24),15,8, edgecolor='black', facecolor="none"))
ax.add_patch(mpatches.Ellipse((30, 24),30,16, edgecolor='black', facecolor="none"))
img_PIL.save(r'C:/Users/image/eye.tif')
```

Comment: you're not actually adding anything to ax...use ax.add_patch(mpl.patches.Ellipse(....))

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem with the drawing, just gotta figure the calculation next

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can define the equation of an ellipse and use it as a mask to see whether or not the tiff array elements are within a defined ellipse or not, if so then avg them, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

#read/define the tiff array
img_array = np.random.rand(101,101)
plt.contourf(img_array)
```

[image: tiff array]

```
#define ellipse parameters and equation (google equation for ellipse)
h = 51
k = 51
a = 10
b = 30

def _in_ellipse(x, y, h, k, a, b):
    z = ((x-h)**2)/a**2 + ((y-k)**2)/b**2
    if z < 1: #the equation is ^ this expression == 1
        return True
    else:
        return False

#vectorize for using on arrays
in_ellipse = np.vectorize(_in_ellipse)

#make a True mask within ellipse
mask = in_ellipse(*np.indices(img_array.shape), h,k,a,b)
plt.contourf(mask)
```

[image: mask]

```
plt.contourf(np.where(mask, img_array, np.nan))
```

[image: masked tiff array]

```
avg = np.nanmean(np.where(mask, img_array, np.nan))
```

you can also add a threshold keyword in there if you want to tweak how the mask behaves around the circumference of the ellipse

```
def _in_ellipse(x, y, h, k, a, b, thresh=1):
    z = ((x-h)**2)/a**2 + ((y-k)**2)/b**2
    if z < thresh:
        return True
    else:
        return False

in_ellipse = np.vectorize(_in_ellipse)
mask = in_ellipse(*np.indices(img_array.shape), h,k,a,b,1.02)
```

[image: threshold]

there are of course more refined ways of doing this, perhaps an opencv approach, but this is as bare bones as it gets

Comment: Cool, but can you explain how do you shape those elipses in rings shapes/ elipsoidal rings? I thought the masks were going to handle it, but not exactly

Comment: im not sure what you mean can you rephrase the question? are you asking how to change the shape of the ellipse?

Comment: Kinda of. I was trying to do ring-like elipses, without fillings, and calculate the area inside the ring boundaries. Following your code, anyone would get disk-like elipses

Comment: I am trying to calculate the mean pixel intensity for sclera and iris separately, in this approach, when calculating for the sclera, it'll take into consideration the iris pixels

Comment: you'll have to make a mask for both scelra and iris, then make a third mask which is the difference of the two, which will give you the "outer" and "inner" ellipses

Comment: sorry meant to say  - will give you the "ring" ellipse ^